# YY/MM dateString to date components

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to convert the date string "06/18" (MM/YY) to the components month and

```
let dateString = "06/18"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/YY"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: date) 
    // contains year: 2017 month: 12 isLeapMonth: false 
}
```

Why are the dateComponents year 2017 and month 12 instead of 2018 and 12?

Is this a timezone issue?

Is there any clean way to get the 2018 and 12?

Comment: Even in the Apple docs: *"A common mistake is to use YYYY."*

Comment: consider always using `yy` instead of `YY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed the `dateFormat` to `MM/yy` from `MM/YY` and you all set to go.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/yy"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {

}
```

Comment: ... well now I feel stupid ;)

Comment: @MarkHim It happens mate :)